# Android: sharedElement-transition has unwanted behavior

Tags: android, layout

In my application i have two Activities. In both Activities, i have a FloatingActionButton at different positions. As i switch from Activity A to Activity B, i want the FloatingActionButton to be moved by a sharedElement-transition. Moving the FloatingActionButton is no problem, everything works correct. However, the image i set as source for the FAB is changed in a weird way.

The first image shows the FAB in Activity A, everything is correct here.
The second image show the FAB in Activity B, but the image on the fab is incorrect.

[image: Activity A: the FAB's image is correct]
[image: Activity B: the FAB's image is scaled or so]

Please see the xml-layout for both of the FABs.

Activity A (as seen in the first screenshot):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_fab"
    android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomBarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
    android:src="@drawable/fabplus"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

Activity B (as seen in the second screenshot):

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_fab"
    android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_normal"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
    android:src="@drawable/fabplus"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

The code i use to start the shareElementTransition is the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, mStartStopButton, getResources().getString(R.string.transition_fab));
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: A question. Why you are using scaleType attribute? Are you using standard icon size for Floating Action Button (24dp, see [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html))? If not you can start by trying to replace your icon with standard size one. Also for width and height you can use `wrap_content`. Hope this could help you.